# Find Array Elements That Meet a Condition

Tags: conditional

I have an array of 5 numbers (say m). I want the following operation

`m=[-1,-3,-2,-5,-4]`
`For (j=1,j==5,j++)`
if `m(j)-m(j+1)>0`

Display the index and array element value of array m and exit the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SequencePosition` to find the positions:

```
m = {-1, -3, -2, -5, -4};

positions = First /@ SequencePosition[m, {x_, y_} /; x > y]
```

> {1, 3}

Then you can get corresponding values:

```
values = m[[pos]]
```

> {-1, -2}

If necessary, you can combine both arrays into one:

```
Transpose[{pos, values}]
```

> {{1, -1}, {3, -2}}

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Transpose@Pick[Most@Transpose[{#, Range@Length@#}], Sign@Differences@#, -1] &; 

{values, positions} = f@{-1, -3, -2, -5, -4}
```

> {{-1, -2}, {1, 3}}

Note: You could similarly modify the answers posted in [your related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149085/125) to get an answer to this question of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Loops are not usually needed in Mathematica to solve problems. Functional Programming and Patterns can do job more efficiently

```
m = {-1, -3, -2, -5, -4};
{Flatten@#, Extract[m, #]}\[Transpose]&@Position[Reverse@Differences[Reverse@m],
_?(# > 0 &)]
(* Note: for a one-dimensional list provided it does not hurt to use Flatten *)

(* {{1, -1}, {3, -2}} *)
```

However, if you want to rely on procedural programming with use of loops you can 
use `Do` or `For`

```
Do[If[m[[i]] - m[[i + 1]] > 0, Print["index: ",i, " value: ",m[[i]]]], {i, Length@m - 1}]
(* index: 1 value: -1 
   index: 3 value: -2
*)
```

Comment: Sir, please also suggest me how to store the result values in an array