# Finding the elements in a list that are less than their successor along with their indices

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

Please suggest how to write following MALTAB code in Mathematica

```
k=1;
for j=1:bb-1
if (aa(j)-aa(j+1))<0
cc(k)=aa(j);
dd(k)=j;
k=k+1;
end
end
```

Here `aa` is some array and `bb` is the length of `aa`.

Comment: A bit rusty on Matlab, but I think `k = 1; For[j = 1, j <= bb - 1, j++, If[aa[[j]] - aa[[j + 1]] < 0, cc[[k]] = aa[[j]]; dd[[k]] = j; ] ]` would be a literal translation (assuming `aa`, `cc` and `dd` are lists/vectors and the first `end` closes the `If` statement with no action if the condition fails... like I said; a bit rusty). But `For` loops are usually the worst of many, many options in Mathematica. A few more details (ie, what is `bb - 1`, how long are your vectors, etc) would help people give better answers.

Comment: Navdeep, this is almost a duplicate of your other question [Find Array Elements That Meet a Condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148669/125). Please consider using the answers there to answer your current question. Also, please remember, when you see good questions and answers, to vote them up by clicking [the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh),  and to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem by clicking [the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)

Answer (score 7):

```
SeedRandom[1];
aa = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 20]
(*{-5, -10, -3, -10, -8, -7, -10, -10, 6, 4, -7, -2, 9, -5, 8, 6, 2, -10, 9, -6}*)
```

To get the positions, you can use [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) and subsequently, to get the elements you can use [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html).

```
ddc = Position[Differences@aa, _?Positive];
dd = ddc[[All,1]];
cc = Extract[aa, ddc]
(*{-10, -10, -8, -10, -7, -2, -5, -10}*)
```

Comment: You need to add `dd = dd[[All, 1]]` at the end to get the `dd` the OP asked for.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be quite fast:

```
f1 = Transpose@Pick[Most @ Transpose[{#, Range @ Length @ #}], Sign @ Differences @ #, 1]&;

f1 @ {-5, -10, -3, -10, -8, -7, -10, -10, 6, 4, -7, -2, 9, -5, 8, 6, 2, -10, 9, -6}
```

> {{-10, -10, -8, -10, -7, -2, -5, -10}, {2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 12, 14, 18}}

**Update:** Timings:

```
ClearAll[f0, f1, aardvark2012F1, aardvark2012F2, anjanKumarF, eldoF, ubpdqnF]
funcs = {f0, f1, aardvark2012F1, aardvark2012F2, anjanKumarF, eldoF, ubpdqnF};
labels = {"f0", "f1", "aardvark2012F1", "aardvark2012F2", "anjanKumarF", "eldoF", "ubpdqnF"};
results = {res0, res1, res2, res3, res4, res5, res6};

f0[a_] := Pick[#, Sign@Differences@a, 1] & /@ {Most@a, Most@Range@Length@a} 
f1[a_] := Transpose@Pick[Most@Transpose[{a, Range@Length@a}], Sign@Differences@a, 1]
aardvark2012F1[a_] := Module[{cc = {}, dd = {}}, Do[If[a[[j]] < a[[j + 1]],
   AppendTo[cc, a[[j]]]; AppendTo[dd, j];], {j, Length@a - 1}]; {cc, dd}]
aardvark2012F2[a_] := Transpose@
  Table[If[a[[j]] < a[[j + 1]], {a[[j]], j}, ## &[]], {j, Length@a - 1}]
anjanKumarF[a_] := Module[{ddc = Position[Differences@a, _?Positive]}, 
  {Extract[a, ddc], ddc[[All, 1]]}]
eldoF[a_] := Transpose[Flatten[#, 1] &@
   Split[MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1]]} &, a], #2[[1]] - #1[[1]] > 0 &][[All, 1 ;; -2]]]
ubpdqnF[a_] := Module[{p = Partition[a, 2, 1]},
  Transpose[Thread[Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#2[[1]], #1[[2]] > #1[[1]]] &, p], 
      True, {a[[#2]], #2} &][[2, 1]]]]]

Equal @@ (#@{-5, -10, -3, -10, -8, -7, -10, -10, 6, 4, -7, -2, 9, -5, 
      8, 6, 2, -10, 9, -6} & /@ funcs)
```

> True

```
SeedRandom[1];
bb = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 100000]; 
timings = Table[First[AbsoluteTiming[results[[j]] = funcs[[j]][bb];]], {j, 7}];
Equal @@ results
```

> True

```
Transpose[{labels, timings}] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"function", "timing"}}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Removing the function `aardvark2012F1` from the list for a test with a larger input size:

```
SeedRandom[1];
bb = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 1000000]; 
timings = Table[First[AbsoluteTiming[results[[j]] = funcs[[j]][bb];]], 
 {j, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7}}];
Equal @@ results[[{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7}]]
```

> True

```
Transpose[{labels[[{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7}]], timings}] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"function", "timing"}}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Maybe even a little bit faster: `Pick[#, Sign@Differences@list, 1] & /@ {Most@list, Most@Range@Length@list}`

Comment: @eldo, I added the function you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**
To dea with clumping from same difference from original code

Just for something different using `Reap` and `Sow` and producing list {index,value}:

```
list = {-5, -10, -3, -10, -8, -7, -10, -10, 6, 4, -7, -2, 9, -5, 8, 6,
    2, -10, 9, -6};
p = Partition[list, 2, 1];
Thread[Reap[
MapIndexed[Sow[#2[[1]], #1[[2]] > #1[[1]]] &, p],True,{#2,list[[#2]]} &][[2,1]]]
```

yielding:

```
(*{{2, -10}, {4, -10}, {5, -8}, {8, -10}, {11, -7}, {12, -2}, {14, -5},{18, -10}}*)
```

Comment: @march  I hope I have corrected my inadvertent deletion of { (in trying to make it fit on line). Thank you for pointing out my error.

Comment: Yeah now it works thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {-5, -10, -3, -10, -8, -7, -10, -10, 6, 4, -7, -2, 9, -5, 8, 6, 2, -10, 9, -6};

Flatten @ Split[list, Less][[All, 1 ;; -2]]
```

> {-10, -10, -8, -10, -7, -2, -5, -10}

To also get the indices:

```
Flatten[#, 1]&@
   Split[
      MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, list], 
   #2[[2]] - #1[[2]] > 0 &][[All, 1 ;; -2]]
```

> {{2, -10}, {4, -10}, {5, -8}, {8, -10}, {11, -7}, {12, -2}, {14, -5},
>    {18, -10}}

Comment: The indices also were requested.

Answer (score 1):

Taking

```
bb = 20;
SeedRandom[1];
aa = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, bb];
```

Here are two possibilities:

```
cc = {}; dd = {};
Do[
 If[aa[[j]] < aa[[j + 1]],
  AppendTo[cc, aa[[j]]];
  AppendTo[dd, j];
  ],
 {j, bb - 1}
 ]
cc
dd

(* cc = {-10, -10, -8, -10, -7, -2, -5, -10} 
   dd = {2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 12, 14, 18} *)
```

Or alternatively,

```
{cc, dd} = 
 Transpose@
  Table[If[aa[[j]] < aa[[j + 1]], {aa[[j]], j}, Nothing], {j, bb - 1}]

(* {{-10, -10, -8, -10, -7, -2, -5, -10}, {2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 12, 14, 18}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks to all for providing solutions

Comment: @NavdeepGoel No worries. Don't forget to select one by clicking on the tick.